# Panning the map to certain extent javascript API

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to limit map extent to the initial extent of the map and limit user from panning more than certain extent.

I tried following but nothing has changed:

```
map = new Map( "map" , {
        basemap: "gray",    
        center: [-85.416, 49.000],
        zoom : 6,
        logo: false,
        sliderStyle: "small"
    });
    var imageParameters = new ImageParameters();
        imageParameters.format = "PNG";

    dojo.connect(map,"onLoad",function(){
        var initExtent = map.extent;

        dojo.create("div",{
          className: "esriSimpleSliderHomeButton",
          onclick: function(){
            map.setExtent(initExtent);
          }
        },dojo.query(".esriSimpleSliderIncrementButton")[0], "after");
      });

    dojo.connect(map, "onExtentChange", function (){
    var initExtent = map.extent;
    var extent = map.extent.getCenter();
    if(initExtent.contains(extent)){}
    else{map.setExtent(initExtent)}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with a similar approach, but instead of setting the map extent to the inital extent, I panned the map back to a point in the initial extent.

See http://jsfiddle.net/bbunker/JP565/ for an example. Hope it helps.